# How to avoid transparency of the inner surface in WebGL?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have the code below. I want both sides of the partial sphere to be non-transparent. Currently, the outer surface is non-transparent, while the inner surface is transparent. What should I do to fix it? Thanks.

```
var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(15, 32, 32, Math.PI + Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2, 0, Math.PI/2);
var sphere_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFFFF00 });
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphere_geometry, sphere_material );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just do the material double side

```js
var sphere_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFFFF00, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
```

Here’s the link to the official doc of [`THREE.Material`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.side)